# Unexpected behaviouf of \DeclareTextFontCommand with IPA font Doulos SIL

Tags: xetex

I'd like to get some text in IPA splitted in paragraphs like the following (I am using xelatex):

```
ʄƥŊ
ƷƝʓɤⱤб
```

When I use `\newcommand` it works (see image below) but not when I use `\DeclareTextFontCommand`. The "ƥ" is missing in the first line and the second line is not printed (see red arrows in image below).

Both commands print the text in two lines when using "normal" characters ("abc 123456789 ilmn xyz").

But the characters are printed in different fonts (see blue boxes for the differences).

What do I miss here?

[image]

Here is the code to reproduce it

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\doulos}{Doulos SIL}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\ipatextfontcommand}{\doulos}

\newcommand{\ipacommand}[1]{\doulos{#1}}

\begin{document}


{\ipatextfontcommand ʄƥŊ

ƷƝʓɤⱤб}

{\ipacommand ʄƥŊ

ƷƝʓɤⱤб}

{\ipatextfontcommand abc 1234567890 ilmn

xyz}

{\ipacommand abc 1234567890 ilmn

xyz}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:**

When using "DejaVu Sans" instead of "Doulos SIL" the command `\DeclareTextFontCommand` switch the font after the first "a" (see red arrow in next image). This was not easily visible in the first image.

[image]

Comment: `\DeclareTextFontCommand` defines command like `\textbf` which expects an argument, it doesn't define a font switch.

Comment: To see what Ulrike has said, try `{\textbf abcd}` and you will see the same effect. Only the first character will be printed in bold typeface. The correct way to type this is to have `\textbf{abcd}`. Similarly, in your code, you either need `\ipatextfontcommand{abcd}` or `{\doulos abcd}`. They will have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer and @Niranjan. This seems to explain the differences. But how do I use a paragraph in `\ipatextfontcommand`?

Comment: you can't (well you can by using \endgraf but you shouldn't). The text commands are meant for small text snippets, for longer parts use the switches (e.g. \doulos directly).

Comment: That means that if I need paragraphs I should use `\newcommand` instead of `\DeclareTextFontCommand`?

Answer (score 2):

A command defined with `\DeclareTextFontCommand` wants the text as argument and doesn't accept `\par`.

You can define an environment for paragraphs in the IPA font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\doulos}{Doulos SIL}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textipa}{\doulos}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ipa}{}{\doulos}{}

\begin{document}


\textipa{ʄƥŊ ƷƝʓɤ б}

\begin{ipa}
ʄƥŊ

ƷƝʓɤ б
\end{ipa}

\end{document}
```

[image]